# PHP and XML: Iterate an XML's leaf elements

Tags: php, xml

I wish to extract the parent of leaf nodes in an `XML` file, with `php`:

```
<root>
     <level name="level1">
       <content name="c1/>
     </level>
     <level name="level2>
       <level name="sub-level-2a">
          <content name="c2" />
       </level>

       <level name="sub-level-2b">
          <level name="sub-sub-level-2b">
             <content name="c3" />
          </level>
       </level>
     </level>
</root>
```

So in the above XML, where the **leaves can be several levels deep**, the elements considered leaves are:

```
<content name="c1" />
<content name="c2" />
<content name="c3" />`
```

How do I extract the `name` property of each of the above leaves' parents, and output for each leaf: `<leaf-name-attribute> - <parent-name-attribute>`?

I have tried:

```
$content_node_parents = $xml->xpath('//content/parent::*');

foreach ($content_node_parents as $content_node_parent) 
{
  echo $content_node_parent['name']." - ".$content_node_parent->content['name']."\n";             
}`
```

The above works perfectly OK but only that `<content>` elements that are not leaves, are also extracted

Comment: what did you try? what exactly do you want as a result? you refer to leave and parent, but your example has content and parent nodes.

Comment: For each `<content>` I want its parent's `name` attribute in `<level>`.

Comment: as a general strategy, select all content nodes by xpath, iterate over them, retrieve their name-attribute and xpath to retrieve their parent's attribute. Feel free to share your code and results and refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath to select needed values

```
//*[*[not(descendant::*)]]/@name | //*[not(descendant::*)]/@name
```

returns

```
Attribute='name="level1"'
Attribute='name="c1"'
Attribute='name="sub-level-2a"'
Attribute='name="c2"'
Attribute='name="sub-sub-level-2b"'
Attribute='name="c3"'
```

Comment: Thanks, but is it also possible to extract the name property of each of their parents?

Comment: For example, so: `//*[*[not(descendant::*)]]/@name | //*[not(descendant::*)]/@name`

Comment: The above does the job, but do you think you can modify your answer to show how to output for each leaf:  `<parent-name> to <leaf-name>`. That is precisely what I am looking for.

Comment: in no way in xpath 1.0

Comment: @splash58 looks like a "please write my code" question to me, don't you think?