# Using XPath to extract XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
   <level name="level1">
       <!-- More children <level> --> 
   </level>

   <level name="level2"> 
       <!-- Some more children <level> --> 
   </level> 
</root>
```

How can I extract a `<level>` directly under `<root>` so that I can run an XPath query such as `$xml->xpath('//some-query')` relative to the extracted `<level>`?

Comment: Did not understood. You want an Xpath to get 1st level node?  `/root/level[1]`

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want/need to split those queries in two parts? (There might be....)

Comment: The `XPath` which I have devised only works when there is only one `<level>` inside root.

Comment: You can limit/pin it to one level element by adding a predicate like e.g. `level[@name="level2"]` to your query.

Comment: My only problem is that my `XPath` query that should follow this step, works by first identifying leaf nodes in the xml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32478608/php-and-xml-iterate-an-xmls-leaf-elements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DOMXPath::query](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)'s second parameter is the context node. Just pass the DOMNode instance you have previously "found" and your query runs "relative" to that node. E.g.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadxml( data() );

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nset = $xpath->query('/root/level[@name="level1"]');
if ( $nset->length < 1 ) {
    die('....no such element');
}
else {
    $elLevel = $nset->item(0);

    foreach( $xpath->query('c', $elLevel) as $elC) {
        echo $elC->nodeValue, "\r\n";
    }
}


function data() {
    return <<< eox
<root>
    <level name="level1">
        <c>C1</c>
        <a>A</a>
        <c>C2</c>
        <b>B</b>
        <c>C3</c>
    </level>
    <level name="level2"> 
        <!-- Some more children <level> --> 
    </level> 
</root>
eox;
}
```

---

But unless you *have to* perform multiple separate (possible complex) subsequent queries, this is most likely not necessary

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadxml( data() );

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach( $xpath->query('/root/level[@name="level1"]/c') as $c ) {
    echo $c->nodeValue, "\r\n"; 
}


function data() {
    return <<< eox
<root>
    <level name="level1">
        <c>C1</c>
        <a>A</a>
        <c>C2</c>
        <b>B</b>
        <c>C3</c>
    </level>
    <level name="level2"> 
        <c>Ahh</c>
        <a>ouch</a>
        <c>no</c>
        <b>wrxl</b>
    </level> 
</root>
eox;
}
```

has the same output using just one query.

Answer (score 7):

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` allows you to fetch node lists and scalar values from a DOM.

So you can fetch a value directly using an Xpath expression:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/root/level[@name="level2"]/@name)')
);
```

Output:

```
string(6) "level2"
```

### The Xpath expression

All `level` element nodes in `root`: 
`/root/level`

That have a specific name attribute: 
`/root/level[@name="level2"]`

The value you like to fetch (`name` attribute for validation): 
`/root/level[@name="level2"]/@name`

Cast into a string, if node was found the result will be an empty string:

`string(/root/level[@name="level2"]/@name)`

### Loop over nodes, use them as context

If you need to execute several expression for the node it might be better to fetch it separately and use `foreach()`. The second argument for `DOMXpath::evaluate()` is the context node.

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/root/level[@name="level2"]') as $level) {
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(@name)', $level)
  );
}
```

### Node list length

If you need to handle that no node was found you can check the `DOMNodeList::$length` property.

```
$levels = $xpath->evaluate('/root/level[@name="level2"]');
if ($levels->length > 0) {
  $level = $levels->item(0);
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(@name)', $level)
  );
} else {
  // no level found
}
```

### count() expression

You can validate that here are elements before with a `count()` expression, too.

```
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('count(/root/level[@name="level2"])')
);
```

Output:

```
float(1)
```

### Boolean result

It is possible to make that a condition in Xpath and return the boolean value.

```
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('count(/root/level[@name="level2"]) > 0')
);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$levels = $dom->getElementsByTagName('level');

foreach ($levels as $level) {
   $levelname = $level->getAttribute('name');
      if ($levelname == 'level1') {
        //do stuff
      } 
}
```

I personally prefer the [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) class for parsing XML.

Comment: The name of the elements is `level` - not `level1`. `level1` is "only" one value of the attribute `name`.

Comment: As I understand it, OP just needs the first one. In this case he would be using the `name` tag inside the element.

Comment: ...but getElementsByTagName doesn't do that in this way. `name` is an attribute, `level1` is one of the values for the attribute `name` in the example document. getElementsByTagName doesn't care about attributes. There is no `<level1>`element in the sample document -> getElementsByTagName('level1') will return an empty list.

Comment: @VolkerK you're perfectly right. I revised my answer. Thank you for the observation.

Comment: ;-) and now for the `on which I can run an XPath query such as $xml->Path('\\some-query')` part of the question. My guess is that this is the real question, not how to "find/extract" one particular level element. But yes, that's speculation.

Comment: Well, I think (without testing) that this should do the trick. Either run the query inside the loop or store the result in an outside variable and use that to do the query.

Comment: Yes, I just believe (time will tell) that the `\\do stuff` part is what the OP wants to know :-]

Comment: So in the `\\do stuff` I have tried `$level->xpath('<a-query>');` this is not applying it to only the children nodes of `<level name="level1">`, but on all the nodes in the XML

Comment: I had a typo. Unfortunately it's case sensitive. I replaced `$level->getAttribute('Name');` with `$level->getAttribute('name');`.

Comment: I have tried again, paying attention to case-sensitiveness in `getAttribute`. But this time, there is a `php` `fatal error`: `Call to undefined method DOMElement::xpath() in ... `. This seem to indicate that it is not possible to `xpath()` on `$level`

Comment: It is possible in the same way as in my answer. ->xpath() is not a method provided by a DOMNode/DOMElement. But you can pass $level to `DOMXPath::query(expression, contenxtnode)` as the context node.

Comment: `DOMXPath::query(expression, contenxtnode)` is not a static function and cannot be called without `DOMXPath` object

Answer (score 2):

Using [querypath](http://querypath.org/) for parsing XML/HTML makes this all super easy.

```
$qp = qp($xml) ;
$levels = $qp->find('root')->eq(0)->find('level') ;

foreach($levels as $level ){
    //do  whatever you want with it , get its xpath , html, attributes etc.
    $level->xpath() ; //
}
```

[Excellent beginner tutorial for Querypath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-querypath/)

Comment: Querypath looks very useful. How do you only `find('level')` that matches a certain attribute, say `leve1l` ? What type of licensing is it on?

Comment: I guess that would be `->find('level[name="level1"]')`, i.e. a css3 selector for the element `level` having the attribute `name` with the value `level1` - except for not having a @ before the attribute's name it's identical to the xpath query in this case.

Comment: In the foreach loop get the attribute name for the level usibg $level->attr('name') then compare it with regular expression. I don't know why I was downvoted , but query part is extremely versatile