# Recursive Method for Array Indexing XML Files

Tags: php, xml

Trying to Recursively Index XML

Been altering listed code but no dice.

```
public function hasChildren($node) {
    if (sizeof($node) != 0) {
        foreach ($node as $value) {
            $value = $this->nodeToIndexedArray($value);
            return $this->hasChildren($value);
        }
    } else {
        return $node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider using xpath rather than traversing xml manually.

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485779/using-xpath-to-extract-xml-in-php

Comment: Why can't I just do it this way? If I handle it recursively well, the function should be fine. My question is more along the lines of where do I make the call for the recursion back.