# Get name of second level tag in XML string

Tags: php, xml-parsing, attributes, simplexml, text-extraction

I am trying to fetch data from an XML file and have converted it to JSON.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('types.xml','SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
```

The XML file contains data structured as:

```
<types>
    <type name="ACOGOptic">
        <nominal>15</nominal>
        <lifetime>14400</lifetime>
        <restock>1800</restock>
        <min>8</min>
        <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
        <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="weapons"/>
        <usage name="Military"/>
    </type>
</types>
```

How can I simply fetch the value of type name="XX"?

In the above case, the desired result would be `ACOGOptic`.

Comment: *"and have converted it to JSON"* What do you mean? Are you *trying* to convert it to JSON?

Comment: And you should show what you have tried.

Comment: Added the json conversion

Comment: You can't automatically convert XML to JSON. You need to do it explicitly.

Comment: This is why I'm having a dumb moment ..
All I'm trying to do is fetch the nominal value & quantmin & quantmax values depending on the value of the name value in the file

Comment: I suggest reading [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Comment: I looked at that before however that doesn't show how to fetch the value of  <type name="ACOGOptic"> for example, only the other values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply iterate over the `type` elements and check the value of the `name` attribute:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<types>
    <type name="ACOGOptic">
        <nominal>15</nominal>
        <lifetime>14400</lifetime>
        <restock>1800</restock>
        <min>8</min>
        <quantmin>-1</quantmin>
        <quantmax>-1</quantmax>
        <cost>100</cost>
        <flags count_in_cargo="0" count_in_hoarder="0" count_in_map="1" count_in_player="0" crafted="0" deloot="0"/>
        <category name="weapons"/>
        <usage name="Military"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Other">
        <nominal>20</nominal>
        <quantmin>0</quantmin>
        <quantmax>30</quantmax>
    </type>
</types>
XML;

$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($sx->type as $type)
{
    if($type['name'] == 'ACOGOptic')
        printf('Nominal: %s  Min: %s  Max: %s  Category: %s', $type->nominal, $type->quantmin, $type->quantmax, $type->category['name']);
}
```

Output:

```
Nominal: 15  Min: -1  Max: -1  category: weapons
```

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense..
I can work with that as there are other items I could work with to group them such as category which I assume would be simply querying the $type->category['name'] value ?

Comment: @ChrisYates I have added the category.

Comment: This is what I've now got and works well to group ... Many thanks for the help :)
```
foreach($xml->type as $type)
{
    if($type->category['name'] == "weapons")
    {
    echo $type['name'].'<br>';
    echo "Nominal : ".$type->nominal.' - Minimum : '.$type->min.'<br><br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated at [Using XPath to extract XML in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32487397/2943403), (although not required in the asked question) xpath is a very direct tool to extract the unknown tag name without looped checks.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aE8nF))

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadxml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(/types/type[@name]/@name)');
// ACOGOptic
```